# Anydesk settings from the command line/edit config files

Tags: command-line, ssh, settings, anydesk

There are multiple users that will use an Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 **hosted on a virtual machine**. I already have X2Go and but I want to switch to Anydesk. I've installed it through X2Go but Anydesk does not show the graphical interface under XFCE so I cannot edit the settings.

I started Anydesk from a SSH session command line, set a password for unattended access but when I try to access it from outside it shows the interactive dialog, not the password prompt. No one is on the virtual machine to give the accept. It don't have keyboard, mouse or monitor.

Where is located the config file for Anydesk in Ubuntu? I would edit the settings manually to have the password prompt, not the interactive one. I cannot find it on the Anydesk web page. Or at least, what is the correct command line to set it from the console?

Comment: We have installed a new virtual machine with Debian. The administrator of the vmware host assign a display to the virtual machine so we can enter the system in the desktop environment (XFCE) so we can enable AnyDesk Unattended access with password. But now we have another problem. AnyDesk access the machine itself, not the user session, so when other user enter in AnyDesk (s)he see my session and have access to my user account.